# How to update with a specific order

Tags: php, mysql

I have different items in a MySql database. The user can create and delete items. The user can decide the order of that items too. I find out a way to get the order that de user decide and store it in a var:

```
$order = $_GET['order'];
```

If I echo this it will give me for example something like this: 2,1,3
That means that the user wants the item with the id 2 be in first place, the item with id 1 in second place and the item 3 in third place...

How can I update the database to save that order that user decided?

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MyTable   
                   SET id=  
                   WHERE  ");
```

(I of course do not know how many items I have, this is something that changes dynamically as the user decides. This is just a simplified example)

Comment: `order` as in the arrangement, or `order` as in a column named "order"?  As far as the database is concerned, you can't rearrange items back-end, but you can sort them when you select.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create an arbitrary ordering list like that.  Not with straight SQL code.

Comment: Mr. Llama: order as an arrangement. I mean, can I change the id 2 to 1, the id 1 to 2?

Comment: You can record any information that the client wants you to in a database. 'Display Order of an item' is just data that needs to be stored in the database and used when the user wants to see the information displayed from the database. It is no different from any other data item that you have to look after.

Answer (score 0):

If you need each `user` to be able to save the order of certain `item`s in the database then I suggest a pivot table `user_item` that stores the `user`'s `id` the `position` they chose for the `item` and the `item`'s `id`..

That way you can `SELECT` on `user_item` using a `JOIN` to `item` and `ORDER BY user_item.position` for a particular `user`'s `id`.

If you only have one user, you could store the `position` column directly in the `item` table.

Comment: Ok, but the question is how can I save in any table that the item with the id 2 has the order 1, the item with the id 2 have the order 1...

Comment: @Nrc, Either loop through your array and run several `UPDATE`s or use a solution similar to Kickstart's

Comment: This is my question. I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

A possible SQL solution to this using a variable.

```
SET @cnt:=0;
UPDATE order_table
SET order_field = @cnt:=@cnt+1
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 3, 2) DESC;
```

This initialises the variable to 0. The update is ordered using the FIELD function. This returns the position of the value of id in the values following. I have put these values in reverse order of what you want them in and used DESC; this is to bypass a minor issue that if the value of id is not one of the specified values then 0 is returned. Without this trick the unspecified ones would have the order field set such that they were listed first.

As each row is updated in order the order fields value is set to the counter variable whose value is incremented at the same time.

Down side is that this is strictly 2 statements, as the variable needs to be initialised. The normal trick to initialise a variable uses a sub query, but that would result in using multiple table syntax for the update query and in that situation the ORDER BY and LIMIt clauses are not supported.